# Receive Android GCM after restarting phone (without running related app)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm guessing this is a really rookie question, so I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction quickly & easily.

I have an app that receives GCM messages.  The code that contains the GcmListenerService-derived class is located within my app.  Because of this, the user MUST run my app after starting their phone in order for my listener to start listening (verified by restarting my phone, sending a test from Postman, and NOT getting the message / notification until I launch my app).

Do I need to create some type of service or something that will allow my app to get new GCM messages, even after restarting the phone (and not launching the app)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need a broadcast receiver which listens on the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast message and launches the push notification service. However, you still have to start the app once to register the receiver. It will also not work if the user force quit the app. There are some approaches, which also will restart the app automatically if the user killed the app, but I think it is a bad practice. In some circumstances the user wants to stop the app and keep it closed.

Comment: I added my BOOT_COMPLETED BroadcastReceiver, started my service in onReceive, and I'm good to go...thanks!